# How to fix iOS 9 window.location issue for backbone.js

Tags: javascript, ios, backbone.js

In iOS 9 beta, a bug (https://openradar.appspot.com/22186109) was introduced that meant that setting `window.location.hash` to some new value was not being updated until "some time" later. The exact meaning of "some time" is up for debate, but seems to be at least until the next js event loop tick.

As an example, you would do something like this:

```
location.hash = "abcd";
console.log(location.hash); // probably not "abcd"

setImmediate(function () {
  console.log(location.hash); // probably "abcd"
});
```

This has caused an issue in our site which is using backbone.js router with hashchange navigation. Imagine that at the start of this example, the route is 'foo', and that before 'foo' in the history was 'quux'.

We do something like this:

```
router.navigate('bar', { trigger: true, replace: false });
```

The backbone.js history class would be invoked and call the routers to handle the navigation:

```
function onFooRoute() {
  router.navigate('baz', { trigger: true, replace: true });
}
```

So we started on 'foo', went to 'bar' and then went to 'baz' (with replace set to true for the last one).

We expect that we should end up on 'baz', and going back in history will take us back to 'foo'.

The issue we saw is that having done all of this, and once everything was settled down, going back in the history via `window.history.back()`, we go back to 'quux' and not 'foo'. It appears that because of the bug, the entry for 'bar' doesn't stick into the browser history stack, and so the navigation to 'baz' replaces 'foo' instead of 'bar'.

My question is how best to fix this? Can I patch backbone.js to work-around this issue?

Answer (score 0):

We resolved it by overwriting a couple of methods in backbone:

```
function isIOS9UIWebView() {
    var userAgent = window.navigator.userAgent;
    return /(iPhone|iPad|iPod).* OS 9_\d/.test(userAgent) && !/Version\/9\./.test(userAgent);
}

//override the backbone.history.loadUrl() and backbone.history.navigate()
//to fix the navigation issue (location.hash not change immediately) on iOS9
if (isIOS9UIWebView()) {
    Backbone.history.loadUrl = function (fragment?: any, oldHash?: any) {
        fragment = this.fragment = this.getFragment(fragment);
        return _.any(this.handlers, function (handler: any): boolean {
            if (handler.route.test(fragment)) {
                function runCallback() {
                    handler.callback(fragment);
                }

                function wait() {
                    if (oldHash === location.hash) {
                        window.setTimeout(wait, 50);
                    } else {
                        runCallback();
                    }
                }
                wait();
                return true;
            }
        });
    };

    Backbone.history.navigate =
    // Attempt to load the current URL fragment. If a route succeeds with a
    // match, returns `true`. If no defined routes matches the fragment,
    // returns `false`.
    function (fragment, options) {
        var pathStripper = /#.*$/;
        if (!Backbone.History.started) return false;
        if (!options || options === true) options = { trigger: !!options };

        var url = this.root + (fragment = this.getFragment(fragment || ''));

        // Strip the hash for matching.
        fragment = fragment.replace(pathStripper, '');

        if (this.fragment === fragment) return;
        this.fragment = fragment;

        // Don't include a trailing slash on the root.
        if (fragment === '' && url !== '/') url = url.slice(0, -1);
        var oldHash = location.hash;
        // If pushState is available, we use it to set the fragment as a real URL.
        if (this._hasPushState) {
            this.history[options.replace ? 'replaceState' : 'pushState']({}, document.title, url);

            // If hash changes haven't been explicitly disabled, update the hash
            // fragment to store history.
        } else if (this._wantsHashChange) {
            this._updateHash(this.location, fragment, options.replace);
            if (this.iframe && (fragment !== this.getFragment(this.getHash(this.iframe)))) {
                // Opening and closing the iframe tricks IE7 and earlier to push a
                // history entry on hash-tag change.  When replace is true, we don't
                // want this.
                if (!options.replace) this.iframe.document.open().close();
                this._updateHash(this.iframe.location, fragment, options.replace);
            }

            // If you've told us that you explicitly don't want fallback hashchange-
            // based history, then `navigate` becomes a page refresh.
        } else {
            return this.location.assign(url);
        }

        if (options.trigger) return this.loadUrl(fragment, oldHash);
    }
}
```